# How do I model this ERD?

Tags: database-design

**The assignment:**

I have an assignment in my textbook, but I don't have the answers available to me until the next lesson in my course. They gave me a story with business rules and I have to create a complete ERD. I've already figured out the following relationship.

[image: ERD]

As you can see a patient stays in one or multiple rooms, and in a room theres 0 or more patients.

**Business Rule:**

`The nurses have to track in what room the patient resides and in what rooms the patient has been before. It's possible for a patient to move rooms.`

**Question:**

Since there's a `n:m` relationship I'm a bit confused as to what cardinality I'm going to have to use when the intermediate table (or child/derived table) comes into play. Can someone explain what symbols (crow foot notation) I'm going to have to use in the following diagram? And **why**?

[image: ERD2]

**N.B.** I added the intermediate table and added an arrival and departure date based on the business rule.

Edit:
Above diagram is wrong, Room code is not a primary key as a patient can only reside in one room at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram should look something like this (Martin notation)

[image: ERD]

An intersection table used to resolve a many-to-many relationship will always have the crows feet, since the intersection table contains foreign keys to the tables that are in the logical M:N relationship.

You can think of it this way:  From each table, look "down"/"along" the relationship at the intersection table and see it with the logical cardinality of the M:N relationship.  For example, the ROOM "sees" many patients (over time and at one time if it is not a private room) so the cardinality at the far end of the ROOM/PLACE relationship is *many*.  You can look at this relationship in the same way to determine optionality.  A room can be empty, so the cardinality for the PLACE/ROOM relationship is **one to zero or more**.

It's a bit more complicated for the PATIENT.  Do you have patient records for patients that are not admitted?  Once they are admitted they can be in various rooms at various times, so that would make it **one to zero or more** for patients too.  If, on the other hand, patients only existed in the context of being admitted to a room, then it would be one to *one* or more, but that doesn't sound like a practical/real world business rule to me.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks alot for the help. If we pretend that patients can be admitted without staying in a room, my first diagram and your diagram would actually mean the same thing, except that your diagram is slightly more detailed. Would you say they're both ERD's? Or could you refer to them individually? If so, what would you name them? Also, I notice the relationships stay exactly the same when you bring in the intermediate child table, except that the parent tables (patient and room) have a `|` (1) symbol near them. Is this always the case with a `n:n` relationship?

Comment: @user1534664 - Both diagrams are ERDs.  They use slightly different graphical conventions, but the most important difference is that yours might be called _conceptual_ because it focuses on entity types and represents relationships at a very high level.  My ERD might be called _logical_ because it drills down on the conceptual level to show how concepts might be represented.  When you show an intersection table as an implementation of M:N it will always* have two 1:M relationships pointing at the entities in the M:N relationship. (*=Always is too strong a word.)

Comment: I take it when you have a single `|` it means you have a cardinality and an optionality of 1?

Comment: In the Martin graphical convention, `|` means one and `|O` means zero or one.  Sometimes exactly one is denoted by two lines: `||` but I've only seen that in textbooks, not in practice.  See here for different graphical conventions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#mediaviewer/File:ERD_Representation.svg